# Show Entries Associated with Category Using Structure

Tags: categories, structure, zoo-triggers

I am designing a site for a wedding show at the moment and I am struggling to get my head around displaying entries related to categories. Basically I have 28 categories Beauty Therapists, Bridalwear, Wedding Cars etc and each of these categories will have entries associated with them.

The page `www.mysite.com/exhibitors/` displays all my categories. I'd like the link to the entries to be `www.mysite.com/exhibitors/beauty-therapists/` and that link to display all the beauty therapists at the show. But at the moment I cannot get the entries to display on the page, in fact I can't even get the page to display.

I'm using the latest version off EE and Structure, I have Zoo Triggers installed also with exhibitors as my trigger keyword.

I can post code if needs be but it is probably something fairly simple, I am new(ish) to EE, have built about 6 sites now but this is the first to incorporate categories. Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Thanks.
Stephen.

********** UPDATE 2 ****************

This is now working correctly. Updated code below in case anyone else come across the same issues. I had to set the setting in Freebie 'Always parse pagination' to yes to make it work.

Happy days.

********** UPDATE 1 ****************

I now have the categories displaying correctly and the entries associated with those categories displaying when the category is clicked, the issue I have now is that I would like to paginate these entries but the pagination is not working.

I should also note this install is in a 'development' folder on my server which is located at www.mysite.com/development.

Exhibitors template code:

```
{embed="includes/siteHeader"}

<body>

{embed="includes/siteTopDetails"}

{embed="includes/brandAndNav"} 

{embed="includes/pageHeading"}

{if freebie_1 == "exhibitors" && freebie_2 == ""}
<section class="mainPage">
    <div class="pageWidth">
        <div class="content noBottomPadding">
            <h3>Exhibitors at the Show</h3>
            <p class="featureText">Over 90 exhibitors ranging from Florists to Photographers to Cake Makers will showcase their products at the Ayrshire Wedding Show over the two days.</p>
        </div><!-- End content -->
    </div><!-- End pageWidth -->
    <div class="exhibitorsWidth">
        <div class="content noTopPadding">
            <div class="exhibitors">
                <ul>
                    {exp:channel:categories channel="exhibitor_individual" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
                    <li><a href="{structure:page:url}{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></li>
                    {/exp:channel:categories}
                </ul>
            </div><!-- End exhibitors -->
        </div><!-- End content -->
    </div><!-- End exhibitorsWidth -->
</section><!-- End mainPage section -->
{/if}

{if freebie_1 == "exhibitors" && freebie_2 != ""}
<section class="mainPage">
    <div class="pageWidth">
        <div class="content noBottomPadding">
            <h3>{exp:freebie:category_name segment="2"}</h3>
        </div><!-- End content -->
    </div><!-- End pageWidth -->
    <div class="exhibitorsWidth">
        <div class="exhibitorsContent">
            <div class="exhibitorsHolder clear">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="exhibitor_individual" dynamic="no" limit="2" category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='2'}" parse="inward" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="{structure:page:uri}/{exp:freebie:category_name segment='2'}"}
                <div class="exhibitorIndividual">
                    <hgroup>
                    <h4>{company_name}</h4>
                    <h5>Stand(s) {stand_number}</h5>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="exhibitorDetailsHolder">
                        <p class="exhibitorDetails"><strong>{exhibitor_name}</strong></p>
                        <p class="exhibitorDetails">{exhibitor_telephone_number}</p>
                        <p class="exhibitorDetails"><a href="http://{exhibitor_web_address}" target="_blank">{exhibitor_web_address}</a></p>
                    </div>
                    {if special_offer_heading}    
                    <a href="#" class="offerLink" data-reveal-id="specialOfferModal" data-animation="fade">Special Offer</a>
                    <!-- Special Offer Modal -->
                    <div id="specialOfferModal" class="reveal-modal">
                        <hgroup>
                            <h3>{special_offer_heading}</h3>
                            <h4>{special_offer_sub_heading}</h4>
                        </hgroup>
                        <p>{special_offer_text}</p>
                        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Special Offer Modal -->
                    {/if}
                </div><!-- End exhibitorIndividual -->
          {paginate}
         <div class="pagination">
         {pagination_links}
            <ul>
                {previous_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Prev</a></li>
                {/previous_page}

                {page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
                {/page}

                {next_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next</a></li>
                {/next_page}
            </ul>
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages</p>
         {/pagination_links}    
         </div><!-- End pagination -->
         {/paginate}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            </div><!-- End exhibitorsHolder -->
        </div><!-- End exhibitorContent -->
        <div class="pageWidth">
            <div class="content noTopPadding noBottomPadding">
                <div class="backToExhibitors">
                    <p class="icon-back"><a href="/development/exhibitors">Back to Exhibitors</a></p>
                </div><!-- End backToExhibitors -->
            </div><!-- End content -->
        </div><!-- End pageWidth -->
    </div><!-- End exhibitorsWidth -->
    <div class="exhibitorsWidth">
        <div class="content noTopPadding">
            <h3>Exhibitor Categories</h3>
                <div class="exhibitorCategories">
                    <ul>
                        {exp:channel:categories channel="exhibitor_individual" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
                                <li><a href="{structure:page:url}{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></li>
                                    {/exp:channel:categories}
                    </ul>
            </div><!-- End exhibitorCategories -->
        </div><!-- End content -->
    </div><!-- End exhibitorsWidth -->
</section><!-- End mainPage -->
{/if}


{embed="includes/siteFooter"}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a 3rd party addon to get the category id from the 2nd segment to use as a parameter in your entries tag. Please post the code as it will help

Comment: OK, that's great thanks. Will update my question to show my code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently with your template setup, there is no way for EE/Structure to tell which template to route to once `segment_2` is available. I've never used Zoo Trigger's before, so this answer is specific using the 3rd party addon - [Freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie):

> Take control of your URLs — define segments that you want EE to ignore
>   completely. Use 'freebie' segments to trigger template behavior, build
>   dynamic archives inside Structure, or just build special URLs for
>   analytics purposes. Freebie allows you to use segments in powerful,
>   flexible ways without the hassle of dealing with strict URL parsing
>   (like Structure's).

In order for this to work, a conditional is needed to determine what type of page is present based of the URL, so if `segment_2` is empty, to show the category listing, if not, show entries specific to present category. The first step is to set a ***breaking segment*** in Freebie's settings: `exhibitors`. Now anything after this segment will be ignored by EE, thus allowing you to use 1 template to control the content. Update the '*Exhibitor*' template with the code below once Freebie is installed & setup.

```
{if freebie_2 == ""} {!-- If segment_2 or freebie_2 is empty, show category listing --}

    <section class="mainPage">
        <div class="pageWidth">
            <div class="content noBottomPadding">
                <h3>Exhibitors at the Show</h3>
                <p class="featureText">Over 90 exhibitors ranging from Florists to Photographers to Cake Makers will showcase their products at the Ayrshire Wedding Show over the two days.</p>
            </div><!-- End content -->
        </div><!-- End pageWidth -->
        <div class="exhibitorsWidth">
            <div class="content noTopPadding">
                <div class="exhibitors">
                    <ul>
                        {exp:channel:categories channel="exhibitors" style="linear"}
                        <li><a href="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></li>
                        {/exp:channel:categories}
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- End exhibitors -->
            </div><!-- End content -->
        </div><!-- End exhibitorsWidth -->
    </section><!-- End mainPage section -->

{if:else} {!-- If freebie_2 is present, show single entry category listing --}

    <section class="mainPage">
        <div class="pageWidth">
            <div class="content noBottomPadding">
                <h3>{exp:freebie:category_name segment="2"}</h3>
            </div><!-- End content -->
        </div><!-- End pageWidth -->
        <div class="exhibitorsWidth">
            <div class="exhibitorsContent">
                <div class="exhibitorsHolder clear">
                    {exp:channel:entries channel="exhibitor_individual" category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment="2"}" disable="member_data"}
                    <div class="exhibitorIndividual">
                        <hgroup>
                        <h4>{company_name}</h4>
                        <h5>{stand_number}</h5>
                        </hgroup>
                        <div class="exhibitorDetailsHolder">
                            <p class="exhibitorDetails"><strong>{exhibitor_name}</strong></p>
                            <p class="exhibitorDetails">{exhibitor_telephone_number}</p>
                            <p class="exhibitorDetails"><a href="http://{exhibitor_web_address}" target="_blank">{exhibitor_web_address}</a></p>
                        </div>
                        {if special_offer_heading}    
                        <a href="#" class="offerLink" data-reveal-id="specialOfferModal" data-animation="fade">Special Offer</a>
                        <!-- Special Offer Modal -->
                        <div id="specialOfferModal" class="reveal-modal">
                            <hgroup>
                                <h3>{special_offer_heading}</h3>
                                <h4>{special_offer_sub_heading}</h4>
                            </hgroup>
                            <p>{special_offer_text}</p>
                            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Special Offer Modal -->
                        {/if}
                    </div><!-- End exhibitorIndividual -->
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                </div><!-- End exhibitorsHolder -->
            </div><!-- End exhibitorContent -->
        </div><!-- End exhibitorsWidth -->
    </section><!-- End mainPage -->

{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately it is still not working. I'll keep digging around to see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Can you update your question with what's happening now? Is the 'Exhibitors' entry in Structure mapped to the correct template?

Comment: OK, I will do. I now have this working but I am looking to paginate my entries that are associated to the categories, but now this not working...

Comment: Hi Siebird. I have this working now, updated code above. I had to set Freebie to always parse pagination for it to work correctly. I really appreciate your time and effort helping me out. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Looking at your code, you can remove the advanced conditionals (ie. `{if freebie_1 == "exhibitors" && freebie_2 != ""}`) to just `{if freebie_2 == ""}` & `{if freebie_2 != ""}` since you have that template mapped directly to the exhibitors entry in structure.